# validating a JSON list as the root object with spring mvc

Tags: json, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I need to validate a JSON list similar to the following:

```
[{"op":"A","path":"C","value":"B"},...]
```

in a Spring MVC application - I am currently deserializing (using default Jackson) to an object along the lines of:

```
public class Operations extends ArrayList<Operation>{}
public class Operation {
     @NotEmpty
     public String op;
     @NotEmpty
     public String path;
     public Object value;

     public void setOp(String op)... and other getters/setters

}
```

but I cannot figure out how to get jsr303 validation provided by reference hibernate implementation to fire for the attributes of Operation.

I can get it to function if I wrap the list in a class but then I have an incorrect format for the JSON, ie something like:

```
{"ops":[{"op":"A",...},...]}
```

is it possible to validate the first object (Operations)? and if not is it possible to serialize the first format (ie the JSON list) to an object of the second format (ie a list wrapped in a placeholder object with a placeholder field)

**Update**
Having failed to find a way to trigger the jsr303 validation on a bare ArrayList I have written a custom jackson json deserializer to stick it into a containing object with an annotated field along the lines of

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=OperationsDeserializer.class)
public class Operations {
    @NotEmpty
    private ArrayList<Operation> ops;
    public void setOps(ArrayList<Operation>ops)...
    public ArrayList<Operation> getOps()...
}
```

This works but now any autogenerated documentation for my api is generating json examples with the dummy "ops" field in it - ie `{"ops" : [ ... ] }`

so the search for a method of triggering jsr303 validation on an ArrayList that is not a field of another object continues - perhaps there is a way to inject a proxy wrapping class at runtime that might work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObjectMapper.class`. it has a method which will convert `Json Object` into `Class Object`

method is , `new ObjectMapper().readValue(String str, Class<T> valueType)`

So you can iterate your Object array, convert to string and pass it to this method to get your result.

so it would look like,

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(object.toString, Operation.class);
```